# How do I change Properties Window's Color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp-xaml

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 along with the Theme Color Editor. I have chosen the dard solarized color for the environment. When working with the XAML Designer, when I select a control, the Properties Window displays a solid white color in the bottom half, which is really annoying considering that everything is dark.

Is there a way I can change this color? I tried to search colors in the theme editor plugin, but I couldn't find any setting corresponding to that...

Thank you

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Properties Window Solarized Dark Theme]

Comment: maybe this link will helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272205/how-to-change-background-color-of-xaml-designer-in-vs2012

Comment: Thank you for the link. It didn't answer my question, but I got a clue as to what to search for. The color settings is **Cider -> ListBackground**. I'll wait a little bit, and if nobody answer, I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, getting a clue from the link Sam Khan provided, I figured it out. You have to change **Cider -> ListBackground** color in the theme editor plugin (You can choose the eyedropper to choose a color from the GUI)

Answer (score 1):

As Farzad said, Cider → ListBackground is important as it affects the items, but  Environment → ToolWindowBackground is also used by the Properties window, which is the color behind all properties.

Note: This window can't handle transparency on its background, unlike others (for those using [MoeIDE](https://github.com/Meowtrix/MoeIDE) or [ClaudiaIDE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbuchi.ClaudiaIDE)).