# How do I turn off this checkered background in the WPF designer window?

Tags: visual-studio

I opened up Visual Studio today, and the WPF designer window has a checkered background.

[image]

As far as I know, it's not a setting I changed. Does anyone know how to turn this off? It's really difficult to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I used the answer posted here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22867273/817630)

> In VS 2013 you can change XAML designer background. Go to:
>
> ```
> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors
> ```
>
> Select:
>
> ```
> Show settings for: XAML UI Designer
> ```
>
> Then set:
>
> ```
> Item foreground : white
> Item background : white or very light grey (custom)
> ```